# iOS 9 custom transition - animationControllerForDismissedController not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9, custom-transition

I am a newbee in iOS development and recently run into this problem with customized transition in iOS 9.

I have an object conforms to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol and implements `animationControllerForDismissedController`, something like:

```
@implementation MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed
{
    MyCustomizedTransitionAnimator *animator = [[MyCustomizedTransitionAnimator alloc] init];
    animator.presenting = NO;
    return animator;
}

@end
```

And the process that triggers the modal transition is something like:

```
@implementation MyViewController

#pragma mark - Initializers

+ (MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate *)modalTransitioningDelegateSingletonInstance;
{
    static MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate *delegateInst = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        delegateInst = [[MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate alloc] init];
    });

    return delegateInst;
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController

- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
{
    [self prepareForDismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:&completion];
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:completion];
}

- (void)prepareForDismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated completion:(dispatch_block_t *)completion;
{
    self.presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    self.presentedViewController.transitioningDelegate = [[self class] modalTransitioningDelegateSingletonInstance];      
}

@end
```

Since `animationControllerForDismissedController` method is not called, the `MyCustomizedTransitionAnimator` is not created, which leads to its `animateTransition` not called either, which causes unexpected problem in my app. (Sorry for my poor English...)

I am also attaching the screenshot of stack trace for both iOS8 & iOS9.
In iOS 8, `animationControllerForDismissedController` is called after the stack trace below.
[image: iOS 8]

But in iOS9, `transitionDidFinish` is called somehow in advance, which I guess probably prevent `animationControllerForDismissedController` being called?
[image: iOS 9: <code>transitionDidFinish</code> is called]

I was wondering if this is an iOS 9 bug or not. Any explanation or work around solution will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you kicking off the modal transition, perhaps you could post code regarding that.

Comment: @beyowulf Just edited it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to use a singleton? Placing + (MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate *)modalTransitioningDelegateSingletonInstance;
 in the view controller is awkward and likely why your delegate is not getting called.

Comment: Why don't you try setting the transitioningDelegate before you present the view controller as apple's own sample code does. If you don't want to provide a custom animation for the presentation of the view controller, in 
- animationControllerForPresentedController:presentingController:sourceController: return nil or don't implement it at all. Thousands of app have custom transition, and they still seem to work on iOS 9.

Comment: have you found solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue.

I hope this will help someone.

What fixed it for me is to make the object which applies `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol as variable instance to keep strong relationship with it.

I think because it gets dismissed after the view is presented first time.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. 
Simply changing the scope of the variable from method to class solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

Turned out I needed to set the delegate on the `navigationController` of the `UIViewController` that contains the trigger button.

Having this old code that didn't work:

```
UIViewController *dvc = [self sourceViewController];
TransitionDelegate *transitionDelegate = [TransitionDelegate new];

dvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
dvc.transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate;

[dvc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I changed the first line to:

```
UIViewController *dvc = [self sourceViewController].navigationController;
```

and it worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect ! Need to set the `transitionDelegate` to the navigation controller if the modal is wrapped in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to say something like:

```
MyDestinationViewController *viewController = [[MyDestinationViewController alloc] init];
MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate *transitioningDelegate = [[MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate alloc]init];
viewController.transitioningDelegate = transitioningDelegate;
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self presentViewController: viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or if you're using segues, in prepareForSegue say something like:

```
MyDestinationViewController *toVC = segue.destinationViewController;
MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate *transitioningDelegate = [[MyCustomizedTransitioningDelegate alloc]init];
toVC.transitioningDelegate = transitioningDelegate;
```

Comment: I think I did that. Please refer to my edit, thanks!