# Xcode 8 Swift 3: Modal presentation transitioning delegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, animation

**Issue**

The delegate functions within 'DrinkTransitioningDelegate' are not called. The 'td' instance remains in memory during and beyond the lifecycle of the presentation.

```
class PresentingViewController: UIViewController {

    let td = DrinkTransitioningDelegate()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = inventory.beverages[indexPath.row]
        item.isSelected = true
        let controller = DrinkViewController(item: item)
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.transitioningDelegate = td
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        //let navCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        //navCon.transitioningDelegate = td
        //navCon.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }

}

class DrinkTransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController!, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return DrinkPresentationViewController(presentedViewController:presented, presenting: presenting)
    }

    let animationController = DrinkAnimatedTransition()

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        animationController.isPresentation = true
        return animationController
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        animationController.isPresentation = false
        return animationController
    }

    deinit {
        print("adf")
    }

}
```

**History**

- The question was raised for iOS 7 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959085/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate-method-not-called-in-ios-7)
- The question was raised for iOS 9 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302830/ios-9-custom-transition-animationcontrollerfordismissedcontroller-not-called)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Solution**

Optional protocol functions are now a thing.

The delegate is comprised completely of optional functions, so there were no warnings.

These functions appeared to the compiler as my own custom functions.

```
func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController!, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return DrinkPresentationViewController(presentedViewController:presented, presenting: presenting)
}

let animationController = DrinkAnimatedTransition()

func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    animationController.isPresentation = true
    return animationController
}

func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    animationController.isPresentation = false
    return animationController
}
```

These are the correct functions.

```
func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return DrinkPresentationViewController(presentedViewController:presented, presenting: presenting)
}

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let animationController = DrinkAnimatedTransition()
    animationController.isPresentation = true
    return animationController
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let animationController = DrinkAnimatedTransition()
    animationController.isPresentation = false
    return animationController
}
```

Comment: I've been stumped on a similar problem for hours... In my case, the two "animationController" functions get called, but not the "presentationController" function. The modalPresentationStyle is .custom. Help! This is driving me completely insane! ;-)

Comment: Okay, figured it out... There's actually _another_ version of `public func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController?` that I copied from some example code. Can't recall the exact wording, but the compiler didn't recognize the error.

Answer (score 3):

Your transitioningDelegate = self may not be called early enough. The solution around my issue was to add the following, then both animationController(forPresented..) and animationController(forDismissed..) we're called.

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    transitioningDelegate = self
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    transitioningDelegate = self

}
```

You may not need the following line, but left in here in many cases if you have a partial half drawer screen.

```
modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Comment: Adding the transitionDelegate to the inits fixed my issue, but I used .custom for the presentation style in order for the presentationController(..) method to work.